# $\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k$ where $A$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, diagonalization

I'm reviewing diagonalization and am wondering if the following makes sense. Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a diagonalizable matrix. That is, there exist matrices $D$ and $P$ such that

$$
A = PDP^{-1}
$$

where the columns of $P$ are linearly independent eigenvectors of $A$ and the $D$ is a diagonal matrix whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues of $A$ (repeated based on their respective multiplicities). Does it follow that

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} A^k = 0
$$

if each eigenvalue of $A$ is in the range $(-1, 1)$? My reasoning is that (from elementary linear algebra) we can show that

$$
A = PD^kP^{-1}
$$

if $A$ is diagonalizable. Since $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are finite, the product should approach zero since each (diagonal) entry of $D$ will approach zero since

$$
\lim_{k \to \infty} \lambda^k = 0
$$

if $-1 < \lambda < 1$. Does this make sense or is my reasoning flawed?

Comment: That's essentially correct (except that you mean $A^k$ at one point instead of $A$). The only other thing is that you could try to look in detail at why, if all the entries of some variable matrix $M$ tend to zero, then all the entries of $PMP^{-1}$ tend to zero. Saying that $P$ and $P^{-1}$ are "finite" is not really a correct argument for this part. Convince yourself instead that the entries of the product matrix are linear functions of the entries of $M$.

Comment: I would hesitate to make such conclusion without a matrix norm. However, I would say that $\lim\limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}A^{k}v=0$ for any vector $v$ with the limit being under the standard norm. You probably would need to make a definition of your matrix norm. I barely deal with matrix norm (especially the non-induced one), so I am not sure if a matrix with small eigenvalue can have large norm

Comment: @Gina If nothing else, one can define the limit of matrices to exist if and only if the limits of all the entries exist, but because we're dealing with finite matrices of a fixed size, this is equivalent to the existence of the limit of matrices with respect to any matrix norm you like.

Comment: No norm is needed here.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that all the operations (sums and products of real numbers) involved in the product $PD^kP^{-1}$ are continuous, you get

$$
\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ A^k = P\cdot \mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ D^k\cdot P^{-1}  \ .
$$

Then, for

$$
D =
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1  &  0         & \dots & 0         \\
0          & \lambda_2  & \dots & 0         \\
\dots                                       \\
0          &  0         & \dots & \lambda_n
\end{pmatrix}
$$

you obviously also have

$$
\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\
D^k =
\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda_1^k  &  0         & \dots & 0         \\
0          & \lambda_2^k  & \dots & 0         \\
\dots                                       \\
0          &  0         & \dots & \lambda_n^k
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ \lambda_1^k  &  0         & \dots & 0         \\
0          & \mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ \lambda_2^k  & \dots & 0         \\
\dots                                       \\
0          &  0         & \dots & \mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ \lambda_n^k
\end{pmatrix}
$$

from which your conclusion follows: if for all $\lambda_i$ you have $|\lambda_i | < 1$, then $\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ \lambda_i^k = 0$, hence $\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ D^k = 0$, hence $\mathrm{lim}_{k\rightarrow \infty}\ A^k = P \cdot 0 \cdot P^{-1} = 0$.

**Remark.** To be picky, that "obviously" over there means something like you are considering the product topology in the space of matrices ${\cal M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and then the continuity of a function of matrices is checked component-wise. So the limit of a function of matrices is the limit of everyone of its components. A similar remark applies for the first statement about the continuity of $PD^kP^{-1}$.